# Is my wifi card broken?

Tags: wireless-networking

I think my wifi card might be broken.

The laptop is an ASUS n53sv: https://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/N53SV/#specifications
The wifi card is an Intel WiFi Link 1000

It just stopped working after my laptop woke up from sleep.

The wifi card is not showing up the device manager. I have tried scanning for HW changes. 
I have tried to reinstalled the driver several times.
I ran a live cd with ubuntu, and it wasn't able to see the wifi card either.

So at this point i think the card might be broken? Have I forgot to check anything?

Comment: You sure have not disabled it with some sort of hardware switch?

Comment: Have you tried removing and reseating the WiFi card?  Specs are not clear on how to do same but perhaps manual will assist

Comment: Open a command prompt (`WinKey+R`) and type in `wmic path win32_networkadapter get name,availability` and hit the Enter key. Does your device show in the list? If yes, what's the number under the "Availability" column?

Comment: @Rambound: Forgot to mention that. I have tried the hardware switch and a keyboard combination (Fn + F2).

Comment: @JSanchez: Yes it does, the number shown is 3. What does that mean?

Comment: It means it's running on full power (everything is OK) Try this: Download devcon.exe (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272) and use the appropriate version (32- or 64-bit) and type in `devcon find =NET` and note the `PCI\VEN...` string for your card. Then type `devcon restart =NET @pci\\VENxxx` where xxx is the rest of the string up to the ampersand for your card. Let us know if that works.

Comment: Strange, I'm on a 64bit win8 and I get the "This app can't run on your PC"-error when trying to open the 64 bit version. Any ideas what could be the issue?

Comment: I was able to run the 32bit though. I was showing my realtek lan controller amoung others, but the wifi card was not on the list. Could it be integrated into the motherboard? I doubt this since i have seen a guy on youtube disassemble the laptop. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L3qNnTVux9Q

Comment: I ran `devcon find pci\*` but the wifi card didn't show here either. (LAN and usb etc did)

Comment: In `Device Manager`, do you see the adapter? Are you able to open its properties and get to the `Details` tab and from the `Property` drop down, select `Hardware Ids`? If so, get the part that starts with `PCI\VEN_xxx` where xxx is the string up to (but not including) the ampersand? Then try the `devcon restart =NET @pci\\VENxxx` as described previously.